# change path from windows to Linux inside configuration files

Tags: loops, for-loop, awk, sed, grep

Hello every one i extracted a zip file from windows to linux
now i used grep to find windows path inside the files

```
 grep -r "D:/Oracle" /u01/app/Middleware/*
```

the output is :

```
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/basicWLSSDomain.py:addTemplate("D:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/domains/sipserverdomain.jar")
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/basicWLSSDomain.py:writeDomain('D:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/basicWLSSDomain')
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/basicWLSDomain.py:readTemplate("D:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/domains/wls.jar")
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/basicWLSDomain.py:writeDomain('D:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/basicWLSDomain')
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/geo1Domain.py:readTemplate("D:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/domains/wls.jar")
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/geo1Domain.py
```

i need a script or a way to change this path to the new path like change

```
 D:/Oracle/ to /u01/app/
```

and ofcourse change \ to / all inside configuration file

lets say that file

```
/u01/app/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/scripts/wlst/basicWLSSDomain.py
```

containing some text includine

```
("D:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/templates/domains/sipserverdomain.jar")
```

i wannt to change D:/Oracle to /u01/app recursively in any file under /u01

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your expected output so it's a guess if this is rally what you want but this **will** do what you say you want to do in your text ("change `D:/Oracle/` to `/u01/app/` and ofcourse change `\` to `/` all"):

```
sed 's~D:/Oracle/~/u01/app/~; s~\\~/~g'
```

Comment: how to apply the code sed 's~D:/Oracle/~/u01/app/~; s~\\~/~g' to replace all text inside files under /u01 recursively ?

Comment: Something like [`find . -exec sed 's~D:/Oracle/~/u01/app/~; s~\\~/~g' {} \;`](http://www.unix.com/man-pages.php?section=0&os=Linux&query=find)...

Comment: Right but add the `-i` option to sed and the `-type f` option to find: `find . -type f -exec sed -i 's~D:/Oracle/~/u01/app/~; s~\\~/~g' {} \;`.